# Is there a easy way to keep the checked state of radio box in any template system?

Tags: python, html, templates, web

Do I really have to suffer this for every `radio` or `check box` if I want to keep the state after submititng the form?

```
   <input type="radio" name="all_gene" class="open_gene" checked=
            % if request.GET.get("all_gene") == "0":
                    checked="checked"
            % endif
     value="0"> <label>One gene</label>

    <input type="radio" name="all_gene" class="open_gene" checked=
            % if request.GET.get("all_gene") == "1":
                    checked="checked"
            % endif
     value="1"> <label>Another gene</label>
```

Comment: don't some browsers just magically remember that stuff?  Anyways, you could try the [yesno](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno) filter instead of the `{% if %}`s, that will at least save a little space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always give the name of the objects and index and use "for" loops for their creation and the "get" function.